# Why can I not pass a "function declaration" as an argument in an event handler function with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, javascript-function-declaration

Why isn't this working using **function declaration**, but it's working perfectly using **function expression**? 
Assuming that the only difference is how the browser loads them into the execution context.

```
function foo(event){
    console.log('in foo');
}

$('.btn').on('click',foo(event)); 

$.ajax({
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('btn').unbind('click');
    },
    success: function(){
        $('btn').bind('click', foo(event));
    }
});
```

With **function expressions** it works great:

```
var foo = function(event){
    console.log('in foo');
}
```

Comment: You realize that `foo(event)` calls the function and passes the return value (`undefined`) to `.bind`?

Comment: Not really because following this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/2326828, foo(event) is declared in the "code region" (before the program gets executed) isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here:

```
$('.btn').on('click',foo(event));
```

you're not passing a "function expression". You're passing the result of **calling** the function "foo".  That's just the way JavaScript syntax works — if you reference a function (by name or otherwise) and follow that with a parenthesized argument list (possibly empty), you're calling the function.

Here:

```
var foo = function(event){
    console.log('in foo');
}
```

you're *creating* a function, not passing it. Note that in your "foo" example the `function` keyword is absent.

If you want to pass the function "foo" as an event handler, just reference it by name:

```
$('.btn').on('click', foo);
```

That passes a reference to the function "foo" *without* calling it.  The jQuery API will get that function reference and use "foo" as the handler for "click" events.

If you need to pass a reference to a function somewhere (like to a jQuery API), and you want the function to be invoked with some additional parameters, you have two choices:

1. Use the `.bind()` method on the Function prototype, or
2. Wrap the function in *another* function yourself.

In the case of a jQuery event handler, a third choice is to provide an object as an argument to `.on()`. That object will be attached to the `event` parameter passed when the event actually happens:

```
function foo(event) {
  var data = event.data;
  if (data.whatever) { // ...
```

Then, when you call `.on()`:

```
$('.btn').on('click', { whatever: true }, foo);
```